# Why i cant get mqtt messages from pythonscript and cant recieve mqtt messages from Node Red?

Tags: python, mqtt

I cant get mqtt messages from pythonscript on Node Red and cant recieve mqtt messages from Node Red.

this is my code:

```
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\user\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py3.10.egg')
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

userdata = "Leer"
client_name = "Pythonscript"
broker_address="000.000.000.000"
port = 1234
topic = "a topic"
subtopic = "fromNodeRed"

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(" client: ",client)
    print(" userdata: ",userdata)
    print(" level: ",level)
    print(" buf: ",buf)

def on_connect(client, userdate, flags, rc):#, message):
    if rc==0:
        print("connected OK ")
        print("Subscribing to topic ",subtopic)#topic)
        client.subscribe(subtopic)
    else:
        print("Bad Connection Returned code=",rc)
    
        
def on_message(client,userdate,msg):
    topic=msg.topic
    m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    print("message recieved",m_decode)
    print("Publishing message to topic ",topic)
    client.publish(topic, "python mqqt message")
        
def on_disconnect(client, userdate, flags, rc=0):
    print("Disconnected result code "+str(rc))

print("creating new instance ",client_name)
client =mqtt.Client(client_name)

client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
client.on_log=on_log
client.on_message=on_message


print("connecting to broker ",broker_address+" :"+str(port))
client.connect(broker_address,port,60)

client.loop_start()



print("Publishing message to topic ",topic)
client.publish(topic, "python mqqt message")

time.sleep(4)
client.loop_stop() 
client.disconnect()
```

I changed some data for protection.

Here is the console output:
[image: Console Output]

I checked the topics, the IP, the Port. Everything seems to be ok.

What do i miss?

Comment: I set up the port for Node Red instead of the Broker .... Problem nr.1 solved. i can send mqtt messages to node red now. but atm i cant recieve...

Comment: Please do not post images of the console output, they are impossible to search and no use to people that need to use screen readers. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Comment: You also need to add a bunch more information about what you are trying to do. Running the loop for just 4 seconds is most likely the problem as that is a small window for a message to be published in. Also the log output is all about the failure to connect, which I assume you have now fixed based on your comment.

Comment: sadly this needs some more debugging.  Do the messages get out?  Looks like they never get sent from the log, but I've never used that library.  Get a known working client connected to the broker and subscribed and check you can send messages with that (e.g. mosquitto).

Comment: and as @hardillb says, remove the sleep and run the code indefinitely first (in general, try to reduce this to the simplest possible code which reproduces the problem, *after* you've confirmed that your broker + topic actually *works* with something like mosquitto.

Comment: publishing messages works now.
but i am troubeling with getting the recieved message out of the function now. 
I will add some buttons to start and stop the loop for recieving messages.
i will make a new post, as the question has changed. is that right ?
thx for your anwsers !
Chorum

Comment: @Chorum yes you should make a new question with a new problem.  If you've fixed this one, you should answer it yourself (and then in a few days you can accept that answer) so the question shows up as solved and people don't stumble on it later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the portnumber from Node Red instead of the mqtt broker.
After that, I recieved and published messages.